# How to append Query parameter in the URL from the controller method in Grails?

Tags: grails

In my jobsController, I have a method named getEmployee(). This method renders view named employee.gsp. 
    render(view : "employee")
When my view is displayed, the url is generated as given below.
http://localhost:8080/test/jobs/getEmployee

Now in this URL I want to append a parameter pagination=false. So my new url should look like:
http://localhost:8080/test/jobs/getEmployee?pagination=false.

How can I do this? Is there any way to append parameters in the generated URL from the controller method getEmployee?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It looks like a workaround for something that could be done better. May I ask what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a trick to do so, **by redirecting to getEmployee action with params.pagination = false**

```
redirect action:'getEmployee', params:[pagination:false]
```

for example

assume I want 'x' parameter in my /cont/checkGet?x=false like this, so I will redirect from 'check' action to 'checkGet' action with x params

```
def check(){
    redirect action:"checkGet",params: [x:false]
}

def checkGet(){
    render "Anshul"
}
```

hope this helps, Thanks

Comment: Thank you Anshul. This really works. Most of my problems are solved now. But there is small problem with it. When I redirect to a new action, the model value is lost.    For Example:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             def check(){
    redirect (action:"checkGet",params: [x:false], model: [command:command)
    }

    Here the value of command is lost.command is null in gsp.

Comment: I guess you can use chain(in place of redirect) or forward in that case.

Comment: chain or forward did not work either Anshul. Same problem.